# How to rotate two strings or functions on page refresh?

Tags: php, random, rotation, shuffle

I have two values, i want to echo one of them on page refresh and rotate it.

If the two values are Hello and Hi.

> Hello > Page refresh > Hi > Page refresh >Hello > Page Refresh > Hi

I tried `shuffle`, `rand`, `mt_rand` but sometimes it just keep the same value instead of rotating to the next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["count"])) $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
$_SESSION["hits"]++;

echo ($_SESSION["hits"]%2 == 1?"Hi":"Hello");

// or with functions

if ($_SESSION["hits"]%2 ==1){
    my_func_1();
} else {
    my_func_2();
}
```

its basically a page hit counter with logic on what to print depending on if the page hits are even or odd.

Comment: It worked, also how to rotate two functions instead of just strings as shown in the above example.

Thanks.

Comment: You are too fast.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the string, something random is definitively *not* what you are seeking.

First to have to decide the scope of the rotation. 
Based on the distributed page from the server ? (odd pages hays hi) or based on the *user* that si visiting you (so the rotation is always visible to you, ever if other users have also the rotation)

I guess you want based on user:

So you have to link the rotation to the user that visit you,
that can be managed through a cookie or through a PHP session

set the cookie and based on the value, say hello or hi

```
// before sending headers
$say = isset($_COOKIE['say'])?$_COOKIE['say']:1;
setCookie('say', $say==1?2:1);

if ($say == 1)
  echo "hello";
else
  echo "hi";
```

You can do the same thing with a PHP session

That gives you an idea

Comment: Thanks but i see the below error,
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function getCookie()"

Comment: Damn you are right, getCookie() does not exist, my mistake, I correct the code